# Remove white spaces left after positioning div

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I am trying to position a very basic div inline with some text.
When I move the div it leaves blank spaces that I can't remove. Would you be kind to guide me with some css tricks for it?

```css
.chord {
  color: orangered;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<br/> Empty
<div class="chord">Bm</div>spaces, what are we living for?<br/><br/> Abandoned
<div class="chord">G</div>places, I guess we know the score <br/>
```

**Fiddle**, in case you want to play with it.

https://jsfiddle.net/rondolfo/r3dphgsL/11/

I did search for an answer and I couldn't find it, but I believe it is a very basic problem for someone that is proficient in css.

Comment: The way I outlined below is optimal since you’re only storing the text for each chord once in the CSS as opposed to everywhere it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-flex` instead of `inline` for the `display` property; and set the `width` to `0`.

That style will remove the space, but will still show the chord text.

You may also remove the `left` spacing and add a space before the div.

```
.chord{
    color: orangered;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup some classes to use as before elements and position them accordingly. You can even make one for each chord as demonstrated below.

```css
.chord{
position: relative;
}
.chord:before{
color: orangered;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: "";
top: -20px;
}
.chord.b-minor:before {
content: "Bm";
}
.chord.g:before {
content: "G";
}
```

```html
<br />
Empty <span class="chord b-minor"></span> spaces, what are we living for?<br/><br/> Abandoned<span class="chord g"></span> places, I guess we know the score <br/>
```